# Check if string exists in array

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array
    `Array = ["AUD/USD"]`
How can I check if `AUD` exists in array without splitting it?

Doesn't seem to work here is my code. Works without `for loop` but not with it.

```
array_list = ["AUD/USD", "EUR/JPY"]
for i in array_list:
    if any('AUD' in s for s in i):
        print("True")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if 'AUD' in Array :
print("Yes, 'AUD' found in array : " , Array)

if 'AUD' not in listOfStrings :
print("Yes, 'AUD' NOT found in array : " , Array)
```

**More details :** [How to Check if an item exists in list ? | Search by Value or Condition](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-check-if-an-item-exists-in-list-search-by-value-or-condition/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `any` function to check each element of the list.

```
if any('AUD' in s for s in Array):
   # do something
```